# Loop within a loop adding to a $total

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, nested-loops

I'm stuck on what I thought was going to be a simple loop.

What I wish to accomplish is to total up the contents of a basket but without adding another users total to it. Here's a much simplified example:

This would work perfectly

```
        foreach($BasketItems as $Items)
        {
            if(strstr($Items, "Book") !== false)
            {
                $ItemPrice += $Items["Price"];
            }
        }
```

But unfortunatley it is construted in such a way that it also loop though all the users, eg:

```
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < mysql_num_rows($Data); $Loop++)
{
        foreach($BasketItems as $Items)
        {
            if(strstr($Items, "Book") !== false)
            {
                $ItemPrice += $Items["Price"];
            }
        }
}
```

The problem with this example is that it adds the previous users `$ItemPrice` to the current one and so on.Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like,

```
for($Loop = 0,$len=mysql_num_rows($Data); $Loop < $len; $Loop++)
{
    foreach($BasketItems as $Items)
    {
       if(strstr($Items, "Book") !== false)
       {
          $ItemPrice[$Loop] += $Items["Price"]; 
          // use Array of $ItemPrice for every user, 
          //you can use user_id here to fetch
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the right track. This loop creates an array of the prices as apposed to calculating the total. Eg `$ItemPrice("2.99","4.99")` instead of `$ItemPrice` with a value of `"7.98"`